# Azure Release pipeline deployment successful but changes not reflected

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

When deployment done through Azure Release pipeline, it got successful but code changes not reflected in the application. There were no errors in the deployment steps and it got successful. Checked logs also no luck. However the same was **successful through manual deployment**

Project Details : C# code

Comment: Where you tried to deploy to? Can you share the yaml file?

Comment: Be careful to run a new pipeline with the `run Pipeline` button and do not rerun using the rerun button in order to fetch latest changes from your code repository

Comment: I am also facing the same issue did you find the answer or does anyone know about this?